# Reactor Schedulers Implementation considerations

Tags: java, scheduler, project-reactor

Lately I am learning a bit of reactor and its implementation of the Schedulers and some questions have jumped into my mind.

First of all, reactor defines a set of scheduler types (i.e. elastic, parallel) which have their own implementation (ElasticScheduler, ParallelScheduler). On the one hand, the parallel scheduler is intended to execute parallel work. For that, the reactor implementation caches *n* ExecutorServices to execute this kind of task.  On the other hand, the elastic in intended to execute blocking tasks. And its implementation caches infinite ExecutorServices for reusing them and evicts them when no necessary.

Having said that, reactor also offers you the possibility of creating your own schedulers from a ExecutorService with `Schedulers.fromExecutorService`.

As far as I see in the code of the reactor Schedulers, the features implemented can be achieved creating a custom scheduler with `Schedulers.fromExecutorService`, so my questions are:

- Why does reactors implement this functionality if it can be achieved through the ExecutorService provided by java?
- Am I wrong with this affirmation?
- Is there something that I did not realize watching the code?
- Is there any risk of implementing my own Schedulers and override the defaults for that purposes?

Thanks!

Comment: How would you create an immediate scheduler with an executor service? Schedulers are an integral part of reactive streams. You can also create your own scheduler without using executor services. I don't understand what point you are trying to make.